# How to check whether UpdatePanel is posting back?

Tags: asp.net, .net, ajax, updatepanel, http-post

Is there a way to determine if an `<asp:UpdatePanel />` has performed an Ajax postback similar to how we can use...

```
if(!Page.IsPostBack) { ...snip }
```

... to determine if a postback from a button submit is taking place.

I'm trying to detect Ajax requests from jQuery, but it's picking up UpdatePanel requests as well which I want to exclude eg...

```
if (Request.IsAjaxRequest() && !Page.IsUpdatePanelPostback)
{
    // Deal with jQuery Ajax
}
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I don't know if this will work any better than your solution, but have you tried?:

```
if (ScriptManager.GetCurrent(Page).IsInAsyncPostBack)
{
    Control ctrl = GetControlThatCausedPostBack(Page);
    if (ctrl is UpdatePanel)
    {
        //handle updatepanel postback
    }
}

private Control GetControlThatCausedPostBack(Page page)
{
    //initialize a control and set it to null
    Control ctrl = null;

    //get the event target name and find the control
    string ctrlName = Page.Request.Params.Get("__EVENTTARGET");
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(ctrlName))
        ctrl = page.FindControl(ctrlName);

    //return the control to the calling method
    return ctrl;
}
```

Comment: I'm wondering if I could use 'ScriptManager.GetCurrent(Page).IsInAsyncPostBack' on it's own, since I guess other controls from ASP.NET AJAX Extensions could fire Ajax request that I don't want to pickup.

Comment: It's worth a shot, I suppose.

Comment: Use ScriptManager.GetCurrent(Page).AsyncPostBackSourceElementID

Answer (score 18):

You can check whether the postback was asynchronous and whether it was issued by an update panel looking at these properties:

```
ScriptManager.GetCurrent(Page).IsInAsyncPostBack
ScriptManager.GetCurrent(Page).AsyncPostBackSourceElementID
```

Answer (score 3):

Try out following:

```
var controlName = Page.Request.Params.Get("__EVENTTARGET");
if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(controlName))
{
     // Use FindControl(controlName) to see whether 
     // control is of UpdatePanel type
}
```

Helpful links:

- [ASP.NET: Recursive FindControl & Extension Methods](http://geekswithblogs.net/QuandaryPhase/archive/2009/05/06/asp.net-recursive-findcontrol-amp-extension-methods.aspx)

Comment: That might work but it only detects a specific UpdatePanel doesn't it? I'm after a more 'generic' solution that detects any UpdatePanel.

Comment: No problems, the you can use FindControl() to see whether this control is of UpdatePanel type... I've updated my answer