# Function is called from a UpdatePanel?

Tags: c#, javascript, custom-controls, updatepanel

I have a common function(custom control's function) that is called from various webpages in the application.
In the common function,I call a javascript like this(Sample Code)-

```
public void ShowMessage(string strMessage)
{
   string s=String.Empty;
   s="<script type='text/javascript'>\n";
   s = s + "alert('+strMessage+');";
   s = s + "</script>";
   Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(typeof(Page), this.ClientID, s);
}
```

When I called this function from a page that is using UpdatePanel,`Page.RegisterStartUpScript` didn't work.
So, I have to use 
`ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Page, Page.GetType(), this.ClientID, s, false);`
Now,I have to pass one more parameter to determine the function was called from UpdatePanel.
Like this-

```
public void ShowMessage(string strMessage,bool isFromUpdatePanel){..}
```

My Question is ,**In the common function,can I know whether the function is called from  UpdatePanel or not(without using parameter)?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an answer and I will use this([got from Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8184331/how-to-check-whether-updatepanel-is-posting-back))-

```
string args= Page.Request.Params.Get("__EVENTTARGET");
if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(args))
{
    //Called From Update Panel(or) UpdatePanel is posting back
}
else
{
    //Called From a page with no Update Panel
}
```

If there is a better solution,please teach me.