# gridview is not updating in update panel

Tags: asp.net, gridview, updatepanel

I have a grid view inside the update panel Like this.

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
<ContentTemplate>


<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" BackColor="White"
                                            BorderColor="#D9EFFD" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1px" CellPadding="3" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1"
                                            Font-Names="Tahoma" Font-Size="8pt" GridLines="Horizontal" Width="100%" ForeColor="#010101"
                                            ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="True">
                                            <Columns>
                                                <asp:BoundField DataField="MODE_TPT_ENTRY" HeaderText="Balance" SortExpression="MODE_TPT_ENTRY">
                                                    <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" />
                                                    <ItemStyle Font-Bold="True" HorizontalAlign="Left" Width="120px" ForeColor="#035BAC" />
                                                </asp:BoundField>
                                                <asp:BoundField DataField="OB" HeaderText="Opening" SortExpression="OB">
                                                    <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Right" Width="70px" />
                                                </asp:BoundField>
                                                <asp:BoundField DataField="ISSUED" HeaderText="Arrival" SortExpression="ISSUED">
                                                    <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Right" Width="70px" />
                                                </asp:BoundField>
                                                <asp:BoundField DataField="UNTARE" HeaderText="UNTARE" SortExpression="UNTARE" Visible="False" />
                                                <asp:BoundField DataField="TARE" HeaderText="Tare" SortExpression="TARE">
                                                    <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Right" Width="70px" />
                                                </asp:BoundField>
                                                <asp:BoundField DataField="BALANCE" HeaderText="Balance" SortExpression="BALANCE">
                                                    <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Right" Width="70px" />
                                                </asp:BoundField>
                                                <asp:BoundField DataField="RRY" HeaderText="Recovery" SortExpression="RRY">
                                                    <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Right" Width="70px" />
                                                </asp:BoundField>
                                                <asp:BoundField DataField="TRANSPORT_NO" HeaderText="TRANSPORT_NO" SortExpression="TRANSPORT_NO"
                                                    Visible="False" />
                                            </Columns>
                                            <FooterStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#000066" />
                                            <HeaderStyle BackColor="#D9EFFD" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#010101" HorizontalAlign="Right" />
                                            <PagerStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#000066" HorizontalAlign="Left" />
                                            <RowStyle ForeColor="#101010" HorizontalAlign="Right" />
                                            <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#669999" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                                            <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#F1F1F1" />
                                            <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#007DBB" />
                                            <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#CAC9C9" />
                                            <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#00547E" />
                                        </asp:GridView>


<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString3 %>"
                                                ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString3.ProviderName %>" SelectCommand="SELECT * from cms_production">
                                            </asp:SqlDataSource>
</ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

and a JavaScript function which is refreshing the panel after 5 seconds like this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.setInterval(function () {
__doPostBack('<%= UpdatePanel1.ClientID %>', '');
        }, 5000);
</script>
```

Problem is that when I change in the data which is bound with gridview then no change shows after five seconds.Can any tell me what is problem in my code or any other additional thing to add in my code to make gridview updated inside the update panel without page redirect.

Comment: Sir I am using Sqldatasource for Binding the Grid.and where to write the `UpdatePanel1.Update();` ?

Comment: Sir sqldatasource is already in contenttemplate and there is no more code except of gridview columns inside the content template

Comment: How do you change the data? Looks like your grid is readonly.

Comment: I change the data in table from oracle database.I am not talking about edit of gridview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to manually update the SqlDataSource each time you postback. If there is no real logic behind it you can just add the following to your Page_Load:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
       .....

    if (IsPostBack)
    {
        SqlDataSource1.DataBind();
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }
}
```

And if you want this done ONLY when the UpdatePanel performs a postback, [use this method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8184608/1379664).

Comment: I think he has to call grid.DataBind() too

Comment: @AmiramKorach haven't tested it but you're probably right. Updated.